# How to get an element by classname out of a form when input is focused

Tags: jquery, html

## I have the following form:

```
<form id="formulier" class="cart" method="post" action="<?php echo makeLink(getCurrentItem()); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" value="productid" name="productId">
        <tr class="lol">
            <td><img src="" width="125" alt="" /></td>
            <td><h3 class="no-mt"><?php echo $cart['name'] ?></h3>
            <p>
                <?php echo substr($cart['description'],0 ,100) ?>
            </p></td>
            <td class="add-to-basket">
            <input type="number" id="modify-number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart['quantity'] ?>" min="1" required />
            <input type="hidden" id="productId" name="productId" value="<?php echo $cart['productId'] ?>" />
            </td>
            <td class="add-to-basket-button">
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" id="remove" name="remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
                </button>
            </fieldset></td>

            <?php $price = $cart['quantity'] * $cart['price'] ?>
            <td class="price"><?php echo  number_format($price, 2)?></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
```

So, when `#modify-number` is `focused`, I want to disable the `#remove button`.

I try to do this like this:

```
    $('#modify-number').focus(function() {
        var price = $(this).parents('#formulier').find('#remove');
        price.prop('disabled', true);
    })
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

anyone out there who  can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `button` with `id` named `remove` not the `td` with class `price`:

```
$('#modify-number').focus(function() {
    $('#remove').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

---

Based on your comment, seem like you have duplicated `id`, `id` must be unique, you need to change all the duplicated `id` using class:

```
<button type="submit" class="remove" name="remove">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

Above is only change the duplicated id of `button` elements, you need to change other elements as well, then you can use:

```
$('#modify-number').focus(function() {
    var removeBtn = $(this).closest('.formulier').find('.remove');
    removeBtn.prop('disabled', true);
})
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that i have more than one form on this page.. The only button that needs to be disabled is the button in the form where the modify-number is focused...

Comment: @BrechtSchepens does that mean you have multiple elements with same id..?

Comment: Oops, changed the question. I have #remove in the .find() :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#modify-number').focus(function() {
  // your other stuff
  $('#remove').attr('disabled',true);
})
```

**Update**
*according to OP's comments*

```
$('#modify-number').focus(function() {
  // your other stuff
$(this).closest('form').find('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
})
```

Comment: @BrechtSchepens check the update. This solution doesn't make use of any id.. (Note that multiple elements with same id in an HTML file is invalid…)